# Cordova Media plugin not working in Android 5.0? (Works fine in 4.4)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

having a bit of a weird issue. My Media plugin is working fine when I test my app on Android 4.4, but when I open it on a 5.0 device I get

`Exception caught during observer callback: ReferenceError: Media is not defined`

which is pretty strange.. I was wondering maybe if there's a way to target sdk version? I'm using HTML5 audio for my sounds which works in Android 5.0 webview, but not in 4.4 webview so I could just use those for android 5.0 if this plugin is buggy in Android 21 or something. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my manifest file? I'm setting my target sdk to 21 and my min to 16.

I'm also having this bug with the Cordova Admob plugin. Works on 4.4, not on 5.0. Does the Media plugin not support Android 21? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but I had similar problems with new Android 5. My problem was that URL media string contained a space, such as

```
http://svlaboratory.org/audio/xlr8r/like/Psalm Pattern.mp3
```

and I fixed it by changing it to

```
http://svlaboratory.org/audio/xlr8r/like/Psalm%20Pattern.mp3
```

by encodeURI.

Comment: @Leandro This does not appear to be a new question.